# Getting the input List of a WHERE IN Filter for SQL QUERY From A File or a Local Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, filter, sql-like

I have a simple SQL Query. However, the query has a where filter which takes a list.

The list contains at least `2000` items and it is becoming extremely inconvenient to put the long list into the query itself.

I was trying to find if I can create a table/ file and call that into the query instead.

EXAMPLE  CODE:

```
Select * from Table_XXXX where  aa = 'yy'  and date > zzz  and mylist = [..............]
```

So instead of the list above, I will like to call the file (locally) in which the elements of the list reside or a table (locally and not in the database)  in which the elements are in a column...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At that point it's probably best to put all the items into a temporary table and use it as a subquery with `IN` or `EXISTS`, or as part of a join.

Comment: Neither of your preferred options are possible in mysql , I don't know about pandas.

Comment: As far as creating a table how can I call a local table and not a table in the database?

Answer (score 0):

First you would store the contents of the file/list in a table. And after that you can use the in condition

```
create table mylist(x int);
insert into mylist values(<all values in your file>);

select * 
  from Table_XXXX tt
 where tt.aa = 'yy' 
   and tt.date > zzz 
   and tt.mylist IN (select x from mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks George. However, I did not get the second line.. Is the insert into my list a function in sql? How can I get the values from file->table->list. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Perhaps i didnt get it correct. is "mylist" a table?

Comment: I have a file with a column which I want to put as a filter for SQL Query as WHERE IN (....)..  So now the next parts I am not sure how to deal with.. Thanks